# Spotify not showing on taskbar

Tags: 12.04, cinnamon, spotify

I'm running `Spotify 1.0.37.152.gc83ea995` in Ubuntu 12.04 over Cinnamon.

When I start it, it doen't show on the taskbar, but it shows on the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> window list.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Are you suing Ubuntu or Mint?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04